# Creating a new instance of a Custom User Model in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a model which is an extension of a User model in Django 1.8. I am also connecting to a MySQL database for this.

```
class LibraryUser(models.Model):
  user_id = models.OneToOneField(User)
  is_catalogue_subscriber = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  is_research_subscriber = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  library_membership_number = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

The reason why I extended the `User` model, of course is to use the authentication framework.

So now, I want to create a new LibraryUser using the `library_membership_number` as the login username. How should I do so? Do I create the `User` first then reference the `LibraryUser`?

ie given `some_` variables either received by a `POST` or by migration of users to the new table

```
u = User.objects.create_user(email=some_email, password=some_password)
lu = LibraryUser(library_membership_number, user_id = u.id)
lu.save()
```

Or is there a correct way to do this? Tried finding online but can't find something to particularly address this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign value to the specify fields as the following:

```
lu = LibraryUser(library_membership_number= '...', user_id = user)
lu.save()
```

- `library_membership_number`

  You can't just assign a variable to `library_membership_number`. `model` is a object containing the fields. You should appoint the field and assign it: `library_membership_number= '...'`, or `model` can't parse which field you  will store.
- `user_id`

  It has defined `foreignkey` in advance. It can accept another `model` object to store: `user_id = user`. Don't call attribute of the `user` to store in `LibraryUser`.